# PHP - Obter valores de Select

Tags: php

Ola,

O meu projeto consiste em... ter um formulario com um select.
Esse select tem:

```
                <form action='/paypoints.php' method='post' id='coin_form'>
                    <select name='payer_amount' class='form-control' required>
                        <option value=''>- Escolher Valor -</option>
                        <option value='2'>3 Pontos - 2 moedas</option>
                        <option value='4'>6 Pontos - 4 moedas</option>
                        <option value='8'>12 Pontos - 8 moedas</option>
                        <option value='16'>24 Pontos - 16 moedas</option>
                        <option value='32'>50 Pontos - 32 moedas</option>
                    </select> 
                    <input type='submit' name='paycoin' class='btn btn-primary-filled btn-left btn-newsletter btn-rounded inside' value='Trocar Moedas'/>
            </form>
```

O meu plano é verificar através de Foreach ou Outro... O valor pedido, exemplo "15".
Ok...

Eu quero é.. Que verifique o Select e se o valor for... 1 ele automaticamente vai bsucar 15... Se for 2, vai bsucar 25..

Existe alguma forma de realizar isso através de Foreach ou outros...

Exemplo codigo:

```
//Se valor for 2
if($ads_selected == 2) {

    //realiza algo... para o 2.                        
}
```

Eu gostaria de obter um While, Foreach seila.. Pois terei de estar sempre a fazer o mesmo codigo para todos os valores... e um unico codigo salvaria muito.

Comment: Será mais fácil se adicionar o código HTML e descrever o que significa o "automaticamente vai buscar" que citou.

Comment: Simplesmente quero que ele va bsucar todos os 2,4,8,16 e 32 valores da Seleçao, e depois verifique qual foi o pedido

Comment: Não está muito claro, pode dar dois exemplos, o que acontece se o valor for 2 e 4?

Comment: ok.. Se o valor for 2, ele pede 3 pontos, e assim adiante.

Comment: Veja se isso essas respostas podem te ajudar
[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/284891/formul%C3%A1rio-interativo-em-html-e-php?noredirect=1#comment580397_284891)

Answer (score 2):

não ficou muito claro o que você quer, mas vou tentar fazer um exemplo para ambos os casos.

**caso 1:**

Primeiro se você quiser fazer algo diferente para cada valor, a melhor forma vai ser utilizar swich e criar um case para cada possível resposta.

```
// paypoints.php
$payerAmount = $_POST['payer_amount'];

switch ($payerAmount) {
    case 2:
        // faz alguma coisa ...
        break;
    case 4:
        // faz alguma coisa ...
        break;
}
```

**caso 2:**

Se o os valores forem tratados iguais pode ser feito utilizando uma implementação utilizando o método [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) para verificar se existe algum valor em um array de valores préviamente declarado.

**exemplo 1:**

```
// paypoints.php
$values = array(2, 4, 8, 16, 32);
$payerAmount = $_POST['payer_amount'];

// verifica se o valor $payerAmount está contino no array $values
if (in_array($payerAmount, $values)) {
    // faz alguma coisa ...
}
```

Outra alternativa melhor que exige um pouco mais de esforço na primeira implementação que concerteza vai te poupar trabalho futuros é utilizar uma [constante](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.constants.php) para criar o select e válidar os dados. Dessa forma os dados ficam centralizado em um só lugar, quando necessário alterar alguma coisa isso será feito somente em um local.

**exemplo 2:**

```
// paypoints.php
const VALUES = array(
    2 => '3 Pontos - 2 moedas',
    4 => '6 Pontos - 4 moedas',
    8 => '12 Pontos - 8 moedas',
    16 => '24 Pontos - 16 moedas',
    32 => '50 Pontos - 32 moedas'
);

// verifica se a variável 'payer_amount' está vindo do post
// essa verificação é necessário pois quando a variável não está
// setada o php enviara uma mensagem 'notice'
if (isset($_POST['payer_amount'])) {
    $payerAmount = $_POST['payer_amount'];

    // verifica se a variável $payerAmount(2,4,8...) é uma key da
    // constante VALUES que foi préviamente declarada.
    if (array_key_exists($payerAmount, VALUES)) {
        // faz alguma coisa
    }
}
```

Para essa segunda implementação também é necessário alterar o arquivo contendo seu html.

```
// formulario.phtml
<?php include ('paypoints.php'); ?>
<form action='paypoints.php' method='post' id='coin_form'>
    <select name='payer_amount' class='form-control' required>
        <option value=''>- Escolher Valor -</option>
        // percorre o constante VALUES (declarada no arquivo paypoints.php
        // botando as chaves da constante (2,4,8..) como value das options
        // e o valor (descrição) como texto de dentro da option 
        <?php foreach (VALUES as $key => $value) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select> 
    <input type='submit' name='paycoin' class='btn btn-primary-filled btn-left btn-newsletter btn-rounded inside' value='Trocar Moedas'/>
</form>
```